# Condicional np.where en Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Quiero crear una columna que se llame 'Comprobación' cuyos valores dependan de los de otras columnas.

Tengo el siguiente dataframe df2:

| Codigo | Descripcion |
| --- | --- |
| 78 | NaN |

y el siguiente código:

`df2['Comprobación'] = np.where(df2['Descripcion'].str.contains('OK'), 'SI', '')`

El problema es que el resultado de la columna comprobacion sale SI cuando debería salir vacío.

| Codigo | Descripcion | Comprobacion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 78 | NaN | SI |

He probado y revisado todo pero no encuentro el fallo.

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Casi lo logras, lo que hace falta es utilizar el argumento `na` de [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) que asigna un valor a los `NaN`.

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Codigo': [78, 87], 'Descripcion': [np.nan, 'Fila OK']})
df['Comprobación'] = np.where(df['Descripcion'].str.contains('OK', na = False), 'SI', '')
print(df)
```

Que imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
   Codigo Descripcion Comprobación
0      78         NaN             
1      87     Fila OK           SI
```

Comment: Muchasd gracias! Ahora sí que funciona! Muy amable!

Comment: Buen día @Víctor, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)